# How to manually migrate a package (no mine) to null safety

Tags: flutter

I search a solution to upgrade my flutter app, but I have some package no longer maintained. I'm lock. So how can I merge last version packages to migrate null safety by myself ?

Possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to https://pub.dev/packages/PACKAGE_NAME.
2. In the tabs on the right, look for the Metadata section. Click the "Repository (Github)" link.
3. [Fork the repository](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo#forking-a-repository), [clone the repo to your local machine](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/cloning-a-repository-from-github/cloning-a-repository#cloning-a-repository) and [migrate the package to null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide).
4. When done, push the local repository to Github.
5. In your *pubspec.yaml*, remove the reference to the old package and replace it with the migrated version:

```
PACKAGE_NAME:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/PACKAGE_NAME.git
      ref: main
```

Comment: You can also drop a PR to the original package so that it benefits others(if merged)